# Is the LastModifiedDate of a deleted record the date that it was deleted?

Tags: soql, soap-api, delete

The question's in the title, really. I'd imagine that `LastModifiedDate` for a deleted record would be the date it was deleted. But, anecdotal evidence from users seems to dispute this...

I've queried some deleted records using `IsDeleted = true` and `ALL ROWS`. All of those deleted records have last modified date of 2017-07-20. There are no records where IsDeleted is false.

Anecdotal evidence from users has that there were some records for that object on 2017-07-21.

So, am I wrong about `LastModifiedDate` for deleted records? Are the users wrong? Is there some other explanation?

Comment: Might be worth looking at `SystemModStamp` as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @AdrianLarson for the suggestion, but SystemModStamp got me the same answer as LastModifiedDate.

The user with the anecdote has just confessed to being confused and misreporting the situation on 2017-07-21.

Which makes me think that LastModifiedDate is going to be the date of deletion. It would be a bit crazy to be anything else. I'll leave this here for a little while in case someone does know better and/or has references confirming that. Otherwise, I guess that this is the answer.

Comment: During the time that the record resides in the Recycle Bin, the LastModifiedDate stamp is indeed the time of deletion, and the LastModifiedById is the user that did the deletion. I'm not sure this is explicitly called out in the documentation, but it is definitely how the system works.