# When soft delete occurs in sfdc, which system date fields (if any) are updated with the date of deletion?

Tags: isdeleted

When a "soft delete" occurs on a record, in SFDC.
the ISDELETED flag is set to TRUE.

but i am not 100% which system audit date fields are updated, if any,
can anyone confirm ?

LastModifiedDate  (y/n)
SystemModstamp (y/n)

This is related to issue:
[Is the LastModifiedDate of a deleted record the date that it was deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185631/is-the-lastmodifieddate-of-a-deleted-record-the-date-that-it-was-deleted)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the same in my personal developer org and when a record is softdeleted then both the LastModifiedDate and SystemModstamp were getting updated with the time of record deletion.

So coming to your question LastModifiedDate and  SystemModstamp are updated